# How to convert a Collection<Collection<Double>> to a List<List<Double>>?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have the following field

```
Collection<Collection<Double>> items
```

and I want to convert it to a

```
List<List<Double>> itemsList
```

I know that I can convert a `Collection` to a `List` by `list.addAll(collection)`, but how can I convert a `Collection` of `Collection`s?

Comment: May I ask, why you need to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Streams :

```
List<List<Double>> itemsList =
    items.stream() // create a Stream<Collection<Double>>
         .map(c->new ArrayList<Double>(c)) // map each Collection<Double> to List<Double>
         .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect to a List<List<Double>>
```

or with a method reference instead of the lambda expression :

```
List<List<Double>> itemsList =
    items.stream() // create a Stream<Collection<Double>>
         .map(ArrayList::new) // map each Collection<Double> to List<Double>
         .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect to a List<List<Double>>
```

A Java 7 solution would require a loop :

```
List<List<Double>> itemsList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
for (Collection<Double> col : items)
    itemsList.add(new ArrayList<Double>(col));
```

Comment: Thank (JAVA) god we now have this stuff too ;-)

Comment: @Eran How could I do the same in Android Studio, because it doesn't recognize stream() and doesn't support lambda expressions?

Comment: @HerBa If it doesn't support Java 8, you'll have to use a loop : `List<List<Double>> itemsList = new ArrayList<>(); for (Collection<Double> col : items) itemsList.add(new ArrayList<Double>(col));`

Comment: Thank you for the responses!